# Pull to Refresh UIWebView

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview

I work with the this tutorial: http://sonnyparlin.com/2011/12/pulltorefresh-ios-5-and-arc-tutorial/

I dont get an error in the code just two things:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PullToRefreshView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I add the QuartzCore framework but it dont help. what I need to do?

thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the PullTorefresh.m to your project too, not just the .h.

Comment: right :)
This would be the easy answer. The problem is something like this.
Are u inserted it using a the .h and .m files, not using library?

Comment: Ok, its work. I dont remember what I do but it work. But i have Another problem: if I'm in the application and in fly mode and i dont have internet its show alert view and dismiss the alert. I go out from the app and i cencel fly mode and i have wifi and i pull the page its dont show the website.

Comment: You should ask a second question if you have a second question.

Comment: Dear user1809478, You created a new question, without closing this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13381162/objective-c-pull-to-refresh

Comment: I new in this website how I close?